# What is "spatted undercarriage"?

Tags: aircraft-design

The [Socata TB-family wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCATA_TB_family) lists the TB-9 and TB-10 as having "spatted undercarriage". What does that mean? From the pictures it appears to be a normal tricycle-gear-setup so I assume it's not referring to the layout of the landing gear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a **spat is a fairing for the gear** to make it more aerodynamic.

[image: spat]

> An aircraft wheel fairing, commonly called a wheel pant or spat or, by
>   some manufacturers, a speed fairing. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_fairing)

Comment: Thanks! I visited that page, but somehow I missed that. I always thought they were simply called "wheel fairings", you learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @roe it doesn't seem like a very common term, more informal and less used in literature. might be limited to the united states as well.

Answer (score 11):

"Spatted undercarriage" refers to **[streamlined fairings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_fairing) on fixed landing gear**. They're also known as **"wheel pants"**, although when it comes to comparisons with clothing **"spats"** is certainly more accurate, as they only cover the top of the wheel, not the entire gear leg.

The term is semi-common in the US, but I've mostly heard (and used) "wheel pants" when talking about landing gear fairings.

#### Spats / wheel pants / fairings on an AA-1's landing gear:

[image: spats on an airplane]

#### Spats on shoes on Charles Sumner:

[image: spats on sumner]